# Using a for loop or other method to tidy up a chained promise

Tags: javascript, json, variables, promise, chain

I've written a function to pull through the contents of 24 individual Google sheets and return them in the correct order, after the promise chain has been fulfilled. I can't work out how to use a loop to cover the 24 id's so that rather than write out the entire chain I can achieve the same with a few lines of code...
Can this be tidied up/written in a more concise way?

```
// Read Google Sheet function
async function readGSheet(docId) {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(docId);
  doc.useApiKey(gSheetApiKey);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[2];
  const rows = await sheet.getRows();
  return rows;
}

// Return Google Sheets in the correct order
function getAllGSheets() {
  let p0 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[0]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p1 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[1]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p2 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[2]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p3 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[3]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p4 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[4]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p5 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[5]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p6 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[6]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p7 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[7]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p8 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[8]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p9 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[9]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p10 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[10]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p11 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[11]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p12 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[12]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p13 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[13]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p14 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[14]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p15 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[15]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p16 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[16]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p17 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[17]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p18 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[18]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p19 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[19]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p20 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[20]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p21 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[21]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p22 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[22]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  let p23 = readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[23]).then(res => {
    return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
  }).catch((err) => { return "[]"; });
  const getAll = async function() {
    let results = await Promise.all([p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23]);
    _database.database.push(results)
  }();
};
```

Comment: I suggest using `map()`.

Answer (score 2):

In the most concise form, this will map over the `gSheetDocIds` passing each to `readGSheet()`. `Promise.all()` resolves to an array of results in the same order as the input array of promises.

```
async function getAllGSheets() {
  return Promise.all(gSheetDocIds.map(readGSheet)).catch(err => [])
}
```

This intentionally neglects the `JSON.stringify()`. The caller can do this on the complete result.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function getAllGSheets() {
  let promises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    promises.push(readGSheet(gSheetDocIds[i]).then(res => {
      return JSON.stringify(res, ['ID', 'Power']);
    }))
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

Comment: Now this one I was able to successfully implement

Answer (score 1):

First I would include the repeated `.then` in `readGSheet`.

```
 async function readGSheet(docId) {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(docId);
    doc.useApiKey(gSheetApiKey);
    await doc.loadInfo();
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[2];
    const rows = await sheet.getRows();
    return JSON.stringify(rows, ['ID', 'Power']);
}
```

Your end goal is to construct the array that you pass to `Promise.all`. It contains a Promise for each item in `gSheetDocIds` . So with a for loop it’d go like this:

```
const promises = []
for (let i = 0; i < gSheetDocIds.length; i++) {
    const gSheetDocId = gSheetDocIds[i]
    const promise = readGSheet(gSheetDocId)
    promises.push(promise)
}
await Promise.all(promises)
```

Or really concisely with `Array.map`:

```
await Promise.all(gSheetDocIds.map(readGSheet))
```